# Playwright throws exception "Browser closed" when testing against MS Edge

Tags: c#, visual-studio, microsoft-edge, mstest, playwright

I'm using Playwright 1.25.0 with Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 on Win 10 x64 to run the following test:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task LoadPlaywrightPage()
{
    var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
    var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
    {
        Headless = false,
        Channel = "msedge"
    });
    var context = await browser.NewContextAsync();
    var page = await context.NewPageAsync();
    await page.GotoAsync("https://playwright.dev/dotnet/");

    Assert.IsTrue((await page.TitleAsync()).Contains("Playwright .NET"));
}
```

This throws the following exception:

> Test method PlaywrightTests.PlaywrightTests.LoadPlaywrightPage threw exception:
> Microsoft.Playwright.PlaywrightException: Browser closed.
> ==================== Browser output: ====================
>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe --disable-field-trial-config --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-back-forward-cache --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,GlobalMediaControls,DestroyProfileOnBrowserClose,MediaRouter,DialMediaRouteProvider,AcceptCHFrame,AutoExpandDetailsElement,CertificateTransparencyComponentUpdater,AvoidUnnecessaryBeforeUnloadCheckSync,Translate --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-sync --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --enable-automation --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --no-service-autorun --export-tagged-pdf --no-sandbox --user-data-dir=C:\Users\MyUserId\AppData\Local\Temp\1\playwright_chromiumdev_profile-XJmwuh --remote-debugging-pipe --no-startup-window
>  pid=35316
> [pid=35316][out] Opening in existing browser session.
> =========================== logs ===========================
>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe --disable-field-trial-config --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-back-forward-cache --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,GlobalMediaControls,DestroyProfileOnBrowserClose,MediaRouter,DialMediaRouteProvider,AcceptCHFrame,AutoExpandDetailsElement,CertificateTransparencyComponentUpdater,AvoidUnnecessaryBeforeUnloadCheckSync,Translate --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-sync --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --enable-automation --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --no-service-autorun --export-tagged-pdf --no-sandbox --user-data-dir=C:\Users\MyUserId\AppData\Local\Temp\1\playwright_chromiumdev_profile-XJmwuh --remote-debugging-pipe --no-startup-window
>  pid=35316
> [pid=35316][out] Opening in existing browser session.
> ============================================================
> at Microsoft.Playwright.Transport.Connection.InnerSendMessageToServerAsync[T](String guid, String method, Object args) in /*/src/Playwright/Transport/Connection.cs:line 167
> at Microsoft.Playwright.Transport.Connection.WrapApiCallAsync[T](Func`1 action, Boolean isInternal)
> at Microsoft.Playwright.Core.BrowserType.LaunchAsync(BrowserTypeLaunchOptions options) in /*/src/Playwright/Core/BrowserType.cs:line 61
> at PlaywrightTests.PlaywrightTests.LoadPlaywrightPage() in C:\MyProjects\PlaywrightPlayground\PlaywrightTests\PlaywrightTests.cs:line 115
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action action)

It also throws the above error when trying to use any "stock browser" (browsers on my pc, not the binaries provided with Playwright). I'm following [the guidance](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/browsers#google-chrome--microsoft-edge) provided on the Playwright site to use the `Channel` setting to indicate which browser to launch.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I followed [this doc](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/intro) then edited the `UnitTest1.cs` file with the code you provide, it works well. The result is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVlul.png. Are you doing the test like this, following the doc? Besides, what do you mean *any "stock browser"*? I think we need to use Playwright  browser binaries. Are you not using that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue: I was running Visual Studio without admin privileges. Once I chose, "Run as administrator", the local MS Edge launched and the test succeeded. Apparently, Playwright needs elevated rights to launch the `Channel` local browsers vs. its own binaries, at least on some setups.

I wish, though, that Playwright could launch the stock browsers without having to have elevated privs.